# How to fetch the key value from object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have stored the value in an object in the following format,

```
$scope.modelName = {
    name: {}
};
```

The value was stored like `{"APLLE":true,"ORANGE":true}`. I am trying to fetch only the key and I am trying to store it in another object using for loop. I couldn't get the value

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {        
    $scope.fruitRulesRules.push({
        field: "fruitName",
        subType: "equals",
        value: Object.Keys($scope.modelName.name[i])
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys()` returns an array of the keys in the object. You need to select the key for index your looping over. You were close but no cigar.

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pzky9owf/1/

```
var modelName = {
        name: {
            APPLE: true,
            ORANGE: true
        }
    },
    fruitRulesRules = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    fruitRulesRules.push({
        field: 'fruitName',
        subType: 'equals',
        /*
            This bit was close. You could could also cache the Object.keys in 
            another variable so its not called in every itteration of the loop if it doesnt change often
        */
        name: Object.keys(modelName.name)[i]
    });
}

console.log(fruitRulesRules);
```

EDIT: Also you've got `Object.Keys`, capital `K`, its lower case `k` but i presume that's a typo writing the fiddle.

EDIT AGAIN: As @KrzysztofSafjanowski mentioned in another comment you can't guarantee the order of `Object.keys()` so even though above works it may not give the desired results.

Ive updated the fiddle to show a different way where the order of the keys is not important: http://jsfiddle.net/pzky9owf/2/

Comment: Thank you . It's working fine. Your explanation was so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are accessing the key wrong, does this give you some insight?

```
Object.keys({"APLLE":true,"ORANGE":true})[0] //returns "Apple"
```

So your solution is possibly:

```
Object.Keys($scope.modelName.name)[i]
```

Comment: JavaScript specification mentions nothing about order of keys - they are not sorted in any way